# Azure Automation Powersell Runbook fails: 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, runbook

I have done all the steps of the following tutorial to have a runbook for automating index and statistic maintenance:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/01/15/automating-azure-sql-db-index-and-statistic-maintenance-using-azure-automation/

I was able to complete all the tutorial without errors, but when I execute the runbook, it returns me an error:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:6 char:16
+ $SQLOutput = $(Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $AzureSQLServerName -Use ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-Sqlcmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What can I do? I use SQL Server with Azure. Specifically, Azure SQL Database with pricing/model tier "S4 Standard (200 DTUs)".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow that blog, I reproduced your error.

You can deploy [sqlserver module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.0.17199) via this page:

[image]

Here is my runbook:

```
$AzureSQLServerName = "jasonsql"
$AzureSQLDatabaseName = "jasondatabase"

$AzureSQLServerName = $AzureSQLServerName + ".database.windows.net"
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "SQLLogin"
$SQLOutput = $(Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $AzureSQLServerName -Username $Cred.UserName -Password $Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password -Database $AzureSQLDatabaseName -Query "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES " -QueryTimeout 65535 -ConnectionTimeout 60 -Verbose) 4>&1

Write-Output $SQLOutput
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! That fixes it. Thank you very much!

Comment: To anyone else running into this, there is a problem with more recent versions of this module. I found other people trying to do azure automation ran into the same issue and were ok after downgrading to 21.0.17199  You can deploy right from the page Jason listed or below: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.0.17199

Comment: I’ve asked relevant question [should-i-use-powershell-subexpression-when-invoke-sqlcmd-in-azure-runbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67453109/should-i-use-powershell-subexpression-when-invoke-sqlcmd-in-azure-runbook) or call Invoke-Sqlcmd directly